# How to interpolate strings in python?

Tags: python

Given a string, I'd like to interpolate it as done by python.

For example, for a string with slash and the letter "n". I'd like to convert it to new line.

Could anybody let me know to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible XY problem. Where are you getting such a string in the first place?

Comment: What is the interpolated value of a new line if not a slash and an n?